# Python Kivy. Negative values

Tags: python, kivy

Hello i have a question i am making a game in Kivy library in Python. I would like to reverse self.hero_pos.points in the function " on_touch_down " i have an idea how to do it by copy pasting coordinates from update_hero and make them negative. But i am curious can i do it in easier way to keep code DRY? :)

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    #what should i do? 
    

 def on_touch_up(self,touch):
   pass

def init_hero(self):
    with self.canvas:
        Color(0,1,0)
        self.hero_pos = Triangle()

def update_hero(self):
    center_x = int(self.width/2) 
    spacing = self.V_spacing * self.width 
    ymax = self.height * self.hero_height
    ymin = self.height * self.hero_height
    x1, y1 = (center_x - spacing*.25, ymin)
    x2, y2 = (center_x - spacing *.5, ymax + ymin)
    x3, y3 = ( center_x - spacing*.75, ymin)
    
    self.hero_pos.points = [ x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3]
```

Comment: What do you mean by reverse? Give an idea off of the values '[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3]'.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. I am unsure by what 'reverse' means.

## Option 1

If reverse means '[y3, x3, y2, x2, y1, x1]', it would be a simple function.

```
def reverse(self):
    return self.hero_pos.points[::-1]
#OR
def reverse(self):
    return self.hero_pos.points.copy().reverse()
```

## Option 2

If by reverse you mean '[x3,y3, x2,y2, x1,y1]':

```
def reverse(self):
    n_points = len(self.hero_pos.points)//2
    ans = []
    for r in range(1, n_points, 2):
        ans.append(self.hero_pos.points[r-1])
        ans.append(self.hero_pos.points[r])
    return ans
```

### Recommendation

I highly recommend you store each x,y value as a pair in a list (a list of pairs). This would make it easier for iteration as well as reordering.

Comment: Thank you for an advice i made a list of pairs. And yeah i wrote my question in a bad way. I would like to make x + spacing instead x - spacing without copy pasting and rewriting everything but it is probably just impossible.